# Django count on a joined table

Tags: python, django

I have a many to many relationship that needs to be counted in Django as well as another column, example....

```
Student:
  ID
  Name
  Lessons

Lesson:
  ID
  Name
  Date
  Type
  Students
```

So now a student has many lessons and a lesson has many students, if I were to do a query where it would show me:

> By month, how many students were overall at all the lessons within that month, and divide them by lesson type as well.

So it would have say:

```
January:
    Maths: 3 lessons, 20 students
    English 3 lessons, 30 students
```

So far this is what I have

```
l = Lessons.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
l = l.values('lesson_type', 'month'
          ).order_by(
             ).annotate(Count('lesson_type')
          ).order_by('lesson_date'
            ).annotate(students=Count('students'))
```

The problem is "when I count for just the amount of lessons I get the correct value", but "when I count for both, the amount of students and the amount of lessons is the same", because of the join. Is there a way to have a sub query for counting a second column?

Better Example:

```
January:
    Lesson 1:
        Type: Math
        Students: 10
    Lesson 2:
        Type: Math
        Students: 3
    Lesson 3:
        Type: Math
        Students: 7
    Lesson 4:
        Type: English
        Students: 13
    Lesson 5:
        Type: English
        Students: 7
February:
    Lesson 1:
        Type: Math
        Students: 10
    Lesson 2:
        Type: Math
        Students: 3
    Lesson 3:
        Type: English
        Students: 7
    Lesson 4:
        Type: English
        Students: 13
    Lesson 5:
        Type: English
        Students: 7
```

So the output should be

```
January:
    Maths: 3 lessons, 20 students
    English: 2 lessons, 20 students
February:
    Maths: 2 lessons, 13 students
    English: 3 lessons, 27 students
```

I just wanna point out that the output is just an example, I don't need it like that, just need that information to be available.

Comment: `and divide them by lesson type as well.` ??

Comment: Yes exactly so you would have in each month how many times a lesson ran, and how many students went to that lesson, so say 20 people in a month went to a maths lesson, and there was 3 lessons in a month

Comment: So if there were 20 students in each three lessons hold in a month then instead of `3 lessons, 60 students`  -- desired output is `3 lessons, 20 students`.

Comment: No no just the total numbers, so X lessons X students, the lessons can have any number of students, so `lesson 1 had 10 students`, `lesson 2 had 3 students` `lesson 3 had 7 students`, and it will show `3 lessons 20 students`.

Comment: I edited the question there, to give a better idea